# CSS float content changes parent position

Tags: css

Why a button with float:left or float:right content changes the button vertical position?
For example http://jsfiddle.net/8ff6dhou/

```
<button>aaa</button>
<button><div style="float:left">bbb</div></button>
<button><div style="float:right">ccc</div></button>
<button>ddd</button>
```

Why the 4 buttons not at same vertical position? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add vertical-align to all to your button.

```
button{vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your div width is not enough for 4 buttons. Increase it!

And there is no point in giving float as left or right to the div. Actually there is no need for the div. Just use the below code:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#eeeeee;margin:10px;">
  <button style="float:left;width:50px;">
    aaa
  </button>
  <button style="float:left;width:50px;">
      bbb
  </button>
  <button style="float:left;width:50px;">
      ccc
  </button>
  <button style="float:left;width:50px;">
    ddd
  </button>
</div>
```

If you float the div inside the button, it will just float in the button while the button position will be the same. You want to float the button, so put style attribute on button!

Comment: So I must wrap ALL button content inside a float div in order to make them same vertical position?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button><div style="float:left">aaa</div></button>
<button><div style="float:left">bbb</div></button>
<button><div style="float:left">ccc</div></button>
<button><div style="float:left">ddd</div></button>
```